# probability of a single point

Tags: probability, limits

Probabilities for an open interval $(a,b)$ where $(a,b)$ are real numbers with $0\leq a <b \leq 1$ are defined as follows :

$$ P[(a, b)]=b-a$$

How to prove that probability for a single point is zero? I guess some limiting procedure is there.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $A\subseteq B$ are subsets of the sample space, then $P(A)\le P(B)$. So, for a single point, since $\{p\}\subseteq (p-\epsilon , p+\epsilon )$ it follows that $P(\{p\})\le 2\cdot \epsilon$. But this holds for all $\epsilon >0$ and so $P(\{p\})=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$$
P((a-\frac{1}{n}, a+\frac{1}{n})). 
$$
This will converge to 0.

Notice that $\{a\}=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-\frac{1}{n}, a+\frac{1}{n})$.